# Tweepy error: code: 261 Application cannot perform write actions. How to work around this?

Tags: python, api, twitter, bots, tweepy

I was just trying to create a bot that uploads a tweet after a time interval (not necessarily regular). However, after a certain amount of tweets my app gets limited and restricted by twitter. Is there a work around for this?
The max number of tweets I've been able to send has been 30. I even tried using sleep() with random time limits but it still doesn't work.

```
import tweepy
import random
import time

consumerKey=''
consumerSecret=''
accessToken=''
accessTokenSec=''

def OAuth():
    try:
        auth=tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumerKey,consumerSecret)
        auth.set_access_token(accessToken,accessTokenSec)
        return auth
        
    except Exception as e:
        return None

oauth=OAuth()
api=tweepy.API(oauth,wait_on_rate_limit=True)

tweets=['i love roses','7 is my favourite number', 'Studies are hard','Guess how many donuts I just ate','A cat ran over my foot']

for i in range(40):
    num2=random.randint(0,4)
    randtime=random.randint(60,120)
    api.update_with_media(imglink,+tweets[num2])
    print("status uploaded")
    time.sleep(randtime)
```

Comment: You can ask to have write restrictions removed via https://help.twitter.com/forms/platform

Comment: @AndyPiper yes ive already applied for that. Thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same problem, unfortunately Twitter API have restrictions for normal users.
You need to are a company or something else. Twitter need to know how you use the data. There is no way sorry...

Answer (score 1):

Same thing happened to me. You could create a new standalone app (in the overview) and replace the consumer and access tokens with the new ones. It worked for me.